# Removing a Website Name in Another Website From Google Index

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I have a website named `indonesiasumateratravel.com`, and when I search on Google something like 'indonesiasumateratravel' or something else, my website's name appears telling me it has been hacked. It looks like this:

[image: Google search results showing highlighted issue]

How can I remove that result, it's really annoying me and customer of course.

---

@All:

Thank you for the quick responses..!

It turns out that the only solution is to report it directly to google, because I realized that the keyword "indonesiasuamteratravel" is under full control of the rogue website. And now that I've reported it to google, and everything is okay.

hehehehe...
:-)

Comment: Hmm, good question! Belongs on http://Webmasters.Stackexchange.com though. No need to do anything, it will be migrated there automatically soon.

Comment: The link in question is: http://www.zone-h.net/mirror/id/14787028

Comment: Let me guess - the number of people who search for "indonesiasumatratravel" is 1 (you). Only site owners do vanity searches. I'd be concerned if the same results occur for "indonesia sumatra travel" (I can't replicate your issue)

Comment: Developers need to make sure the site is secure and on secure servers before releasing it in the wild. An Ounce of Prevention is worth A Pound of Cure in this situation. Zone-H is quite a popular site that documents defacements and has been around so long that you'll have a hard time outranking them in search. Get your inbound link count up there and get a couple of friends in the travel industry to feature travelling in Sumatera (sp). Most of the world knows it as Sumatra, so a couple popular mentions using your spelling should move them and you up.

Comment: And as Mike says, worry more about "Indonesia Sumatera Travel". Your potential customers don't glue words together and you will be more hurt by that being buried 20 pages down than the unliklihood of someone accidentally doing a SITE: search on your domain and running across Zone-H entries.

Answer (score 4):

As the site you linked for the keyword [indonesiasumateratrave.com <sup>*Zone-H Defacement Mirror*</sup>](http://www.zone-h.net/mirror/id/14787028) is not under your control, you can not do much about it.

That site is documenting site defacements, pretty much what the press does by taking photographs from crime scenes probably. I don't think that zone-h will remove it from their listing (which would remove it from the google serps sometime later).

Google itself decides on the ranking itself and you normally have no influence on that as well.

Anyway, as there is not much you can do about, you should better live with it, you're in good company with many companies and institutions worldwide if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the website that archives the defaced website has better pagerank than your original site. Unfortunately there's not much you can to but wait and hope that your original site's pagerank gets improved.

Comment: PageRank has little to do with "ranking" these days.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to replicate your results. I'd suggest however, that your easiest option for getting the zone-h site pushed down below the fold at least is to get some site-links for your site. Google just added a new site link format for branded searches that really take up a lot of space.
http://www.seroundtable.com/google-big-sitelinks-13877.html

Once you've secured your site links you can build some links to other sites that direct people to you (your Facebook page, linkedin company page, twitter account etc.) these sites have a lot of authority and should be able to outrank zone-h with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a better response on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

However, looks like you can't do anything other than reporting it to google and trying to get a better rank. The top site simply has more clout for that keyword than you and will show up above your ranking. I notice the same site shows up below your page as well.